# Convex set positive operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

$V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space with a hermitian inner product.

Let $T \in End_{\mathbb C} V $ is positive if $(Ta, a ) \geq 0$ for all $a \in V$.

Let $X=\{ T \in End_{\mathbb C} : 1-T^*T \text{ is positive } \}$. Let $U, W \in X$. How can I show that $(U + W)/2 \in X$? Here $T^*$ represents the adjoint operator of $T$.

Comment: Is $V$ a Hilbert space? (Better not to use the same name $V$ for different things in the same text).

Comment: V is a finite dimensional complex vector with an hermitian inner product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $T \in X$ iff $\|Ta\| \le \|a\|$ for all $a \in V$.